# adding multiple header text to excel file while exporting data in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

[image]I want to add multiple header text in excel file when export to excel.  I 
I want a code for windows application.

```
protected void ExportCGICReportToExcelRel(DataSet dsResult, int number)
{
    try
    {
        string data = null, data1 = null;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (j = 0; j <= dsResult.Tables[1].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            data1 = dsResult.Tables[1].Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = data1;
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= dsResult.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dsResult.Tables[1].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                data = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = "'" + data;
             }
         }
         if (number == 1)
         {
             if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileCASHLESS))
             {
                 System.IO.File.Delete(fileCASHLESS);
             }
             xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileCASHLESS, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
          }
          else if (number == 2)
          {
          }

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to do the heading at the very top (Weekly Claims Report...) then you want merged cells.  Create a range object that encompasses the cells you want to merge and then call the merge method on it...

```
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1],xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,6]);
range.Merge(true);
```